# Is there any way to add Bearer Token to headers instead of params in SignalR?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I use Angular5+ (frontend) and .Net Core 3.1 (backend)

When I use Angular and the accessTokenFactory while building the signalR connection, the bearer token is sent with the HTTP request as "ws://localhost:4200/test?id=xxxxx&access_token=yyyyyyyy". Nevertheless, the token is sent like a parameter instead of a header value.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

When using a browser the token must be included in the query string because headers cannot be set on the WebSocket in the browser. If you're using Node, then headers are allowed and the token could be set in a header instead.

File an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore to fix it.

Right now it just assumes that the url will be needed, but it could be updated to take Node into account. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/db8a6497042f2d2a730c1ee09ad3641502acf802/src/SignalR/clients/ts/signalr/src/WebSocketTransport.ts#L46

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use headers when using websockets.
However [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-5.0#access-token-logging) article regarding security considerations when using signalr might be helpful.